# Split a column after specific characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field data in mysql db. For example

```
quot_number
====================
UMAC/ARC/161299/801
UMAC/LAK/151542/1051
UMAC/LAK/150958/00050
```

Iam expecting an output as below:

```
801
1051
00050
```

Actually the last numbers or characters after the last '/' has to be shown in my sql query. Any ways to achieve it?

I tried to add something like this, but not getting expected result:

```
LEFT(quotation.quot_number, 16) as quot_number4

right(quot_number,((CHAR_LENGTH(quot_number))-(InStr(quot_number,',')))) as quot_number5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use function `substring_index`.

```
select
    substring_index(quot_number, '/', -1)
from yourtable
```